# How can I use Bootstrap with a CMS that uses a old version of jQuery? I tried noconflict mode, but can't get it to run properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The CMS I'm using uses jQuery v1.7.1 and has lots of components dependent on it. Of course, Bootstrap requires v1.9.1. I'm basically trying to use two versions of jQuery - one for the CMS and the other for Bootstrap. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script>var jQuery_1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Changed all '$' to 'jQuery_1_10_2' in v1.10.2 and it still didn't work. According to what I've read, the CMS can place it's jQuery link either before or after those listed here. Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello,  could you elaborate on what CMS you're using and exactly what errors you are experiencing?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It's a proprietary CMS. Either I get on error telling me that Bootstrap needs v1.9.1 or higher to work, or I get errors that the scripts run by the CMS won't work. I believe it was always one or the other depending on different things I've tried, never both.